# TsUml is not creating connection between classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, uml, class-diagram

I have this assignment where i have to generate a class diagram from TypeScript files. I have successfully downloaded TsUml and it generates the classes without any connections between them

I 've tried re-writing the tsconfig.json file as shown below but it still doesn't work.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/__tests__/*.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```